# How do I write a class that behaves like a numpy.ndarray without subclassing numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume the following given class definition:

```
class Numeric(object):
  def __init__(self, signal):
    self.signal = signal
```

Now, with the requirement that `Numeric` doesn't inherit from `numpy.ndarray`, how do I have to extend that definition that `Numeric` behaves like a `numpy.ndarray`?

**edit:** `signal` should be a `np.ndarray` (or similar, like `quantities.Quantity`). I have the following scenarious in mind:

```
import numpy as np
import quantities as pq

a = Numeric(pq.Quantity([1,2,3], 'mV'))
b = Numeric(pq.Quantity([1,3,5], 's'))
c = Numeric(np.array([10,20,30]))

a = Numeric(np.array([1,2,3]))
b = Numeric(np.array([1,3,5]))
a * c
a * b
a * np.array([3,4,5])
```

and:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(b)
```

Comment: Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: Is there any particular bit of ndarray's behaviour that you want? It's quite a big thing.

Comment: You'll never get full `ndarray` behavior without subclassing, since some Numpy operations like `asarray` behave differently depending on whether they get an `ndarray` instance or something else.

Comment: The requirement comes from SQLAlchemy when I want to map the object to a table.

Comment: I would like to use arithmetic functions and things like plot(Numeric(np.array([1,2,3])).

Comment: Have you looked at the numpy source?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it's not ok for your "Numeric" class to be subclassed from ndarray?  E.g., does this SQLAlchemy-related requirement dictate that you use some specific base class?  If so, then can you get away with just using multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

With a decorator for adapting `numpy`-functions and an implementation of `__array__` within `Numeric` I can solve most problems:

```
def adapt_signal_functions(cls):
  def generateAdjustedFunction(functionName):
    print functionName
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
      function = getattr(self.signal.__class__, functionName)
      return function(self.signal, *args, **kwargs)
    return foo
  functionNames = [
      '_get_units',
      '_set_units',
      'rescale',
      'ptp',
      'clip',
      'copy',
      'compress',
      'conj',
      'cumprod',
      'cumsum',
      'diagonal',
      'dot',
      'flatten',
      'getfield',
      'round',
      'trace',
      'max',
      'mean',
      'min',
      'newbyteorder',
      'prod',
      'ravel',
      'reshape',
      'resize',
      'round',
      'std',
      'sum',
      'trace',
      'transpose',
      'var',
      '__getitem__',
      '__getslice__',
      '__abs__',
      #
      '__add__',
      '__div__',
      '__divmod__',
      '__floordiv__'
      '__mod__',
      '__mul__',
      '__pow__',
      '__sub__',
      #
      '__radd__',
      '__div__',
      '__divmod__',
      '__rfloordiv__',
      '__rmod__',
      '__imul__',
      #'__rmul__',
      '__rpow__',
      '__rsub__',
      ]
  for functionName in functionNames:
    foo = generateAdjustedFunction(functionName)
    setattr(cls, functionName, foo)
  return cls


@adapt_signal_functions
class Numeric(object):
  def __init__(self, signal):
    self.signal = signal
    self.adapt_quantity()

  def adapt_quantity(self):
    if hasattr(self.signal, '_dimensionality'):
      self._dimensionality = self.signal._dimensionality
      self.dimensionality = self.signal.dimensionality

  def __array__(self):
    return self.signal
```

With that I can do:

```
import numpy as np
import quantities as pq

a = Numeric(pq.Quantity([1,2,3], 'mV'))
b = Numeric(pq.Quantity([1,3,5], 's'))
c = Numeric(np.array([10,20,30]))
n =  np.array([1,2,3])

a * a
a * c
a * n
a.max()

print type(a * n) == type(a.signal *  n)
# >>> True
print type(a * c) == type(a.signal *  c.signal)
# >>> True
```

Return types correspond to the equivalent return type of `Numeric.signal`.

One problem remains:

```
print type(n * a) == type(n * a.signal)
# >>> False
```

Any ideas, how to fix that?

Comment: What is "quantities"?  Is that something defined in SQLAlchemy?  Or something you defined yourself?  (Or something else?)

Comment: @EdwardLoper - I'd assume it's this unit conversion library: http://packages.python.org/quantities/user/tutorial.html

Comment: Exactly, and `pq.Quantity` inherits from `numpy.ndarray`.